# Branched Galois covers of affine space with Galois group isomorphic to the permutation group.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory

Is there an easy description of all Galois, flat and branched covers of $\mathbb{A}^n_{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}}$ with Galois group isomorphic to the permutation group $S_m$? ($m$ can be any number but the answer might differ based how it compares to $n$). For example is it true that irreducible components of such a cover is necessarily isomorphic to the affine space?